# What is the best way to fix this simple Dart Null error?

Tags: string, flutter, function, dart, null

I'm following along with an online course and the instructor gave this example of code...but it now throws a Null Safety error...

"The parameter 'namePerson' can't have a value of null beccause of its type..but the implicit default value is null'

```
void main() {     
     
  greet(greeting: 'Hey', namePerson: 'Cindy');
  }

void greet({String namePerson, String greeting}){
    print("$greeting $namePerson");
  }
```

Now after researching this I found I could fix the error in three ways..by placing a ? after the word String...or by placing the word 'required' before the String...or by giving a default value...eg.

```
void greet({String namePerson = 'Bob', String greeting = 'Sam'}){
```

I don't really understand though what we should ideally do in a situation like this?
I watched a Youtube video on null safety errors'..but it is still a bit beyond my current comprehension level. Can someone explain how and why you would solve this error? Thanks for any help or tips!

Answer (score 1):

You should start by asking you "In the context of my function, are my parameters required of optionnal" ?

Clearly, a function to greet someone should have :

- a required, so **non nullable** `namePerson`: you must have a name to greet someone. And you cannot have a defaultValue (arbitrary "Bob" ? why ? it doesn't really make sense)
- an optional greeting but with a default value, so **non nullable** also : you must say something to him to greet him

So I'd have it like :

```
void greet({required String namePerson, String greeting = 'Hello'}){
```

So basically, you should separate the 2 aspects :

- should the inner body of my function works with a nullable or non nullable value ?
- should my function take a required, optional but non nullable (so with default) value, or a totally optional one (!nullable) ?

Hope that helped

Comment: Thanks so much...you actually helped me solve the next tutorial in the series too...this particular course is a little outdated now...but the 'required' word is making all the difference! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use null check operator . Your code will run. Use the code like below. Thanks.

```
void main() {     
         
      greet(greeting: 'Hey', namePerson: 'Cindy');
      }
    
    void greet({String? namePerson, String? greeting}){
        print("$greeting! $namePerson!");
      }
```